# django floppy forms geospatial widgets error

Tags: geodjango

I'm trying to define a view that lets the user edit the data in the database, I'm using floppyforms, because of its geodjango widgets which is part of the form that i would want the user to use for adding and editing/updating their data so this here's the code:

```
def editPath(request, path_id, template_name="routes/path_form.html"):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated():
        return redirect('/login')
else:
    try:
        path = Path.objects.get(pk=path_id)
    except Path.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404
    if path_id is not None:
        if request.method == "POST":
            form = PathForm(request.POST, instance=path)
            if form.is_valid():
                s = form.save()

                return redirect("/route#paths")
        else:
            form = PathForm(instance=path)
    else:
        form = PathForm()

    return render_to_response(template_name, locals(), context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

but when i save it, i get this type error that says:

> *strftime() argument 1 must be string or read-only buffer, not tuple*

I think the error is with the floppyforms geodjango widget for the path field, am i missing something?  or did i get my view wrong? thanks in advance.

I'm using the widgets for linestrings from floppyforms